# I can't show the ajax Request Response in my html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

guys i'm trying to work with ajax, i send the request to the server when a button clicked, then it's must return some HTML and show it, in the div with the id="formTag", but it's doesn't work can'i get some advice,
Her is my code:

```
var ajaxRequest; // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
function ajaxFunction() {
try {

    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e) {

    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try {
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {

        try {
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {

            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
  }
}

function getForm(objButton) {
ajaxFunction();
if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
   document.getElementById("formTag").innerHTML = ajaxRequest.Response;
}
   var buttonValue = objButton.value;
   ajaxRequest.open("get", "get-form/" + buttonValue, true);
   ajaxRequest.send();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getForm(objButton) {
    ajaxFunction();
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange=function{
        if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
            document.getElementById("formTag").innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;//property responseText contain data from server
        }
    }
    var buttonValue = objButton.value;
    ajaxRequest.open("get", "get-form/" + buttonValue, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);//parameter null is necessary even you don't pass data
}
```

you could try this.